# Webdriver ruby, URL with same path not working in two of seven sites

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have used the same method to logout a logged user to the site. And that method is going to the same URL that one "logout" button opens when you click it. I used that method because the button is inside a dropdown and is easier to open the "**@driver.get ENV['base_url'] + "logout"**" method.

The thing is that this method is working in 5 out of 7 sites, and more strange is that if i copy+paste the logout url manually, the behaviour is the spected one, and the user logoffs, but the same action via webdriver is not working in some sites that are identical between them.

```
ENV['base_url'] = 'http://lucyvideo.com.co/'
@driver.get ENV['base_url']
(I login the user)
@driver.get ENV['base_url'] + "logout"
```

Comment: What happens in those 2 sites?

Comment: the page reloads and the user is still logged in. The same happends if the url go to other paths, like the user profile, etc. In all other sites works okay, but those two, only reload the homepage without the path. but if you manually paste the url with the path, it works okay, that is confusing me.

Comment: But initially going to the site and logging in works?

Comment: yes, that works perfect.

Comment: With Devise and other similar authentication packages, logging out is done with a DELETE action, not a GET. Have you tried @driver.delete url ?

Comment: Hi @ReggieB you mean replacing that in this line: "@driver.get ENV['base_url'] + "logout""?

Comment: I tried with "@driver.delete ENV['base_url'] + "logout"" but it gives me "undefined method `delete' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x00000001b61b28>"

Comment: Yes I did, but I assumed @driver was containing an http client of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it... seems that webdriver didn't like the URLs without "www", I don't know why I tried to add that and it worked OK.

So, instead of "http://lucyvideo.com.co/"

I tried: "http://www.lucyvideo.com.co/"

And is working fine.